# templating a string comparator correctly in c++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, comparator

I wrote a comparator for strings in c++

```
    template <class T> class AStringComparator   // primary template declaration
    {
        public:
            bool operator()( T, T );
    };


    template <> class AStringComparator<std::basic_string<char> >
    {
        public:
        bool operator()( std::basic_string<char> _A, std::basic_string<char> _B )
        {
                //all the code here
            }
    }
```

Then, I tried to template it to `const char*` like this:

```
template <> class AStringComparator<char const *>
{
    public:
        bool operator()( char const * _A, char const * _B )
        {
            AStringComparator<std::basic_string<char> > S;
            std::basic_string<char> a(_A);
            std::basic_string<char> b(_B);
            S( a, b );
        }
};
```

This compiles and runes, but produces wrong results almost always. I think I have made a mistake in implementing the `const char*` version. Can you please point it out. My intention was to convert the `const char*`'s to basic_string and then let the original function for basic_string that I wrote and that works properly do the work. But something has gone horribly wrong.

Comment: Just a heads up, underscore and an uppercase letter afterwards are reserved identifiers.

Comment: `return S(a,b);` Right now you don't return anything (and your compiler should issue a warning).

Comment: @jrok OMG so sorry to bother people like this. Thanks for pointing it out btw. its 4 am here. hence the stupidity. Please add it as an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @jrok COmpiler did not issue any warnings .. I do not have strict or wall turned on .. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Potatoswatter It did the solve the problem. I am making it a point to fix all the variable names though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Actualy returning the result is what fixed the issue. See the last line in the specialization.

Comment: @jrok My bad, I thought he'd replied to Rapptz implying that comment was the solution.

Comment: @Wildling There, did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specialization is missing a return statement:

```
bool operator()( char const * _A, char const * _B )
{
    AStringComparator<std::basic_string<char> > S;
    std::basic_string<char> a(_A);
    std::basic_string<char> b(_B);
    S( a, b );  // <----------------- should be return S(a,b);
}
```

This is undefined behaviour. In practice it results in a random true/false at the call site and that's why it seems to be "almost always wrong".